# I don't understand what exactly does the function bytesToWrite() Qt

Tags: qt, qtcpsocket

I searched for `bytesToWrite` in doc and that what I found "For buffered devices, this function returns the number of bytes waiting to be written. For devices with no buffer, this function returns 0."

First what does mean buffered devices. And can anyone please explain to me what exactly this function does and where or how can I use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many IO devices are *buffered*, which means that data isn't sent straight away, but it is accumulated to be sent in bulk when there is a sufficient amount.

This is done essentially to have better performance, as sending data normally has some fixed overhead (at the very least the syscall overhead), which is well amortized when sending data in bulk, but would have to be paid for each write if no buffering would be used.

(notice that here we are only talking about `QIODevice` buffers, normally there are *also* all kinds of kernel-mode buffers and buffers internal to hardware devices themselves)

`bytesToWrite` tells you how much stuff is in the `QIODevice` write buffer, i.e. how many bytes you wrote that are waiting to be *actually* written (as in, given to the OS to write).

I never actually had to use that member, but I suppose it could be useful e.g. to in a producer-consumer scenario (=if the write buffer is lower than something, then you have to actually calculate the next chunk of data to send), to manually handle buffering in some places or even just for debugging/logging purposes.

Answer (score 0):

it's actually very usefull when you're using an asynchronous API.
you can for example, use it inside a bytesWritten() slot to tell wether the buffer is empty and the data has been fully written or not.